# Codeigniter how to retrieve base_url from database in php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

As I am retrieving a column of content in html form, from database as this column contain text and image which is retrieved through base url();

see example:

```
<p>Although the complexities, individualities and uniqueness of the human mind is beyond 
imagination, let alone comprehension.</p>

<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/uploads/guide-banner.jpg" alt="guide" />
```

data mentioned above is stored in database field. I can retrieve html fine but I can't access `base_url()` from database field, help me what i'm doing wrong calling php while we are already in php ??

Comment: try concatenating base_url()
<img src="'.base_url().'" assets/uploads/guide-banner.jpg" alt="guide" />
    )

Comment: concatenating the base_url(); didn't solve the issue ???? need help some other way .....

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this syntax to retrieve image from database in codeignitor

```
<?php foreach($results_partners as $part) { ?>
    <a href="main/partner" class="roller-item fancybox fancybox.ajax">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url() .'cms/uploads/partners/thumb_290/'.$part->partner_image; ?>" style="width:264px; height:263px;"> 
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: the image is not a different field its a tag in html full text content where site base url is difined by base_url(); for images.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute PHP code inside PHP code !. I think we can do some trick to make PHP chunks executable.

At this point we need JavaScript capabilities , you have to put that column content into JavaScript variable , then output that variable to your page while loading. You can notice at that moment your PHP code converted to real output !

I hope this helping you !

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this syntax.

`<img src="' . base_url() . 'assets/uploads/guide-banner.jpg " alt="guide" />'`

Comment: concatenating the base_url(); didn't solve the issue ???? need help some other way .....

Comment: you have to check the base_url() using print_r(base_url());

Comment: have you save the settings in config/ autoload.php   $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Answer (score 0):

assign your `base_url()` to a variable like

```
$base_url = base_url();
```

modify your code as shown

```
<p>Although the complexities, individualities and uniqueness of the human mind is beyond 
imagination, let alone comprehension.</p>

<img src="{$base_url}assets/uploads/guide-banner.jpg" alt="guide" />
      ---^
```

Comment: src="{$baseurl}assets/uploads/new.jpg" this i have taken from inspector this how the output is in html, variable outputs as string its not returning its value.

Answer (score 0):

it will solve this: change your base_url(); to the content of base_url : exp:http://localhost/blablabla;
through var_dump(base_url());